# clangd on linux cannot find default headers

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, emacs, clang

I've installed the newest LLVM toolchain from the official PPA, including clang, clang-tools-extra, lldb, lld, libc++ and libc++abi. I'm trying to use [clangd with emacs + lsp](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clangd/).

All works fine except clangd cannot find default headers like memory, vector and so on. My code is fine, it is normally compiled using clang. My compile_commands.json also okay.

How to make clangd work?

Edit: removed mention about building llvm+clang from sources since it has been done incorrectly.

Comment: You should probably state the steps you used to build LLVM. There are optional components that can be built, and they are sensitive to location in the build tree. Did you also build and install `libc++` and `libc++abi`? Also see [Noloader | build-llvm.sh](https://github.com/noloader/build-llvm/blob/master/build-llvm.sh). It builds an older version of Clang but shows you how to place components in the tree before configure.

Comment: I've removed mention about building llvm from source since I haven't install it. Probably this was the case but I guess everything should work fine after installation from the official ppa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any info on the internet, so posting the solution here.
Suppose the llvm toolchain is installed in `/usr/lib/llvm-8`.
The answer is:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/llvm-8/include/c++/v1 /usr/include/c++/v1
```

That's it. Good luck.

Comment: This does not sound correct to me. The compiler is supposed to know where its C++ headers are. It sounds like the build scripts have a problem.

Comment: I've installed all llvm packages including libc++. The thing is clang itself and clangd for some reason have different logic of finding libc++ headers on linux, so clang works just fine, clangd doedn't. After digging into clang and clangd source code I've decided to try to link libc++ headers location to the place clang uses on linux and it finally worked.

Comment: Btw [this line](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/c1c29fb987dd01ef0624f38996ebfc05d2f8841b/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp#L470) pushed me to try this workaround.